# In c++ how to remove letter from a string and add a number to int from the letter

Tags: c++, string

What I am what to do is have a String with something like AABBCC as the value for the string. What I am trying to do is a loop that look at the first letter in the string variable and remove that first letter, and add a number to a int variable base on the number.
So basely what I am looking for is say.

string LettertoNumber = AABBCC

loop

take first letter in LettertoNumber

remove the First Letter A

add 1 to int variable

end loop when A is not the First letter anymore

loop

take First Letter in LettertoNumber B

remove the First Letter B

add 2 to int variable

end loop when B is not the First letter anymore

loop

take First Letter in LettertoNumber C

remove the First Letter C

add 3 to int variable

end loop when C is not the First letter anymore

Now I can find out how to add up a number using a int variable.
What I can't find out is how remove from a string base on what said.
I am looking for a way I can do this that I can understand.

Comment: If the string is implemented as an array, removing from the front could be expensive. If the exercise is just to "add up" each letter, do you have to remove them?

Comment: What code have you tried? We can't code the whole assignment for you. That would be cheating.

Comment: sorry I never expected the whole assignment to be done by you guy I just needed a pointer in the right directions, because I have no idea how to do this part.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the letters, just traverse the string and update the sum accordingly:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size();) {

  do {
    // as long as:
    //  1. you are not at the end of the string 
    //  and 
    //  2. there is a sequence of equal chars
    // update your sum accordingly
    sum += value_you_want_for(s[i]);
    i++;
  } while (i < s.size() && s[i - 1] == s[i]) 

}
cout << sum;
```

If you *really, really* want to remove chars you could use the [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) method of the `std::string`.